# Ошибка TokenMismatchException в Laravel

Tags: laravel, csrf

Добавил все ajax запросы в исключения, но все равно выкидывает ошибку. Как найти проблемный участок кода из лога ничего не понятно

```
exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException'
in /var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:53
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#1 /var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 /var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 [internal function]: Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#4 /var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(62): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 [internal function]: Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#7 /var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#8 /var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#10 /var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 /var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#13 /var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 /var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(42): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#16 /var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#17 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 /var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 /var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#20 /var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(87): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 /var/www/site/public/index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 {main}
```

Comment: проблема только при ajax?

Comment: а бывают подобные ошибки не только при ajax? ну я честно то и не знаю, мне надо роут найти которые подобную ошибку вызывает в трейсе его нету где можно найти?

Comment: Сессия создаётся?

Comment: А как это определить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в странице с которой вы отправляете ajax попробуйте добавить в head:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
```

а в js добавте:

```
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }
    });
});
```

если вы отправляете форму при помощи ajax добавте в тело формы

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

и собственно добавте в отправляемые даные нужно указать токен, например

```
formData['_token'] = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
formData['username'] = $('input[name="username"]').val();
formData['password'] = $('input[name="password"]').val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/url',
    data: formData,
    dataType: "json",
...
```

если же нужно полностью отключить, открой файл app/Http/Kernel.php и закоментируй строку, но это не самая лучшая идея

```
'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken'
```

надеюсь поможет

Comment: Так вопрос то не совсем об этом, а о том узнать какой скрипт эту ошибку вызывает и при каких условиях, но скорее всего придется именно токен отправлять везде

Comment: Антон, я поправил ответ.

Comment: ну полностью отключать не кошерно мало ли атаки действительно будут